# Batch not Working (If)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**master.bat**

```
@echo off
    if !%~1! == !--Instance! (
        if !%~2! == !old! (
            echo Old instance
            set /p InstanceId= Enter the InstanceId:
            echo %InstanceId%
        )
        if !%~2! == !new! (
            echo New instance
        )
    ) else (
        if !%~1! neq !--Instance! (
            echo Bad command: Unknown Flag/Switch %1    
        ) else (
            if !%~2! neq !new! **(
                echo Bad command: Incorrect Flag value %2
            )
        )
    )
```

**Q1 :** The above piece of code works fine for all the conditions except the last one marked as (**) for readbility. I am not able to comprehend why ?
    i am running the following command

```
master.bat --Instance abc
```

**Q2:** also i wish to change the same (**) line to check for another value say 'old' (quotes for clarity). how to do that ? will this work

`if !%~2! neq !new! or !%~2! neq !old! (
      echo Bad command: Incorrect Flag value %2
 )`

Comment: `!` can have a special meaning in batch files. Why exactly are you using them? Are you using delayed expansion to dereference the variable name or just using the exclamation points as delimiters?

Comment: i dont know their exact meaning, i am using them as delimiters i guess !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**answer for q1 :** Finally i recognized where i was going wrong, actually the control was never reaching the block with (**).

**answer for q2 :** and making slight changes in the code snippet above it will work in the manner expected.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if !%~1! == !--Instance! (
    if !%~2! == !old! (
        echo Old instance
        echo %InstanceId%
        set /p InstanceId= Enter the InstanceId: 
        call DescribeOldEC2.bat %InstanceId%
        echo %InstanceId%
    ) else (
        if !%~2! == !new! (
            echo New instance
        ) else (
            echo Bad command: Incorrect Flag value %2
        )
    )   
) else (
    if !%~1! neq !--Instance! (
        echo Bad command: Unknown Flag/Switch %1    
    ) 

endlocal
```

Comment: do yourself a favour and use quotes `"` instead of exclamation marks `!`. Although `!` are working here, they will bring you big trouble sooner or later.

Comment: You don't need the IF in you last ELSE clause - You have already proven that %~1 neq --Instance at that point.

Comment: @Stephan , initially i used to use `""` but they used to give me trouble, then i saw  `!`used somewhere and it never gave me any trouble though i still do not know how `""` or  `!` actually works. can you please point me somewhere useful on this ?

Comment: @dbenham ya you are correct, but i am keeping that to make code more readable, what do you think about it ?

Comment: If you really want to document the meaning of the ELSE, then I would use a comment, not another IF statement. You could add a REM comment, or use `) else ( %= neq --Instance =%`